# AcceptSecurityContext error when using ldapsearch against Active Directory

Tags: ldap

I am using `ldapsearch` to try to connect to an Active Directory LDAP server using this command (running on Ubuntu Linux):

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://SRV001 -D acme\SVC_LDAP_A -w mySecretPassword
```

However, I get:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you need to quote the username, so change the command to:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://SRV001 -D "acme\SVC_LDAP_A" -w mySecretPassword
```